Issues uploading and transforming images
I'm running into issues when uploading images, both locally (DDEV) and in staging environments. Attempting to upload images to staging gives a generic:

Upload failed for “example-image.jpg"

Locally I get the message:

'Unknown or bad format ( seconds) at position
0 (s): The timezone could not be found in the database'.

Log files contain errors relating to image transforms:
Failed to generate transform with id of 1. at /home/forge/staging.example.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/imagetransforms/ImageTransformer.php:153)\n[previous exception] [object] (DateMalformedIntervalStringException(code: 0): Unknown or bad format ( seconds) at position 0 (s): The timezone could not be found in the database at /home/forge/staging.example.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/DateTimeHelper.php:718) 


PHP: 8.3.2
Linux 6.6.16-linuxkit
MySQL 8.0.33
Imagick 3.7.0 (ImageMagick 6.9.11-60)
Craft Pro 4.8.9 (Latest)
Yii: 2.0.48.1
Twig: v3.8.0
Guzzle: 7.8.1

Plugins (all latest versions):

Amazon S3: 2.2.1
Carbon Emissions Tracker: 4.1.0
CKEditor: 3.8.3
Hyper: 1.1.27
ImageOptimize: 4.0.7
Navigation: 2.0.27
SEOmatic: 4.0.48
Typogrify: 4.0.3
Vite: 4.0.9

Any ideas of how I can resolve this issue? I've already tried rolling back to earlier versions of Craft, ImageOptimize and aws-s3, without success.

Looking through my image volume settings I noticed the value expires: ' seconds' which did not appear on my other volumes. I changed that to expires: '' ran ddev craft up and my images volume immediately began to behave as expected, with image transforms appearing in the control panel and uploads working.

